# How can I modify my JavaScript code to ensure that the timer starts at 30 seconds every time a player's turn begins, and switches to the next player?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a memory game. each player has 30 seconds to choose 2 cards. if the cards are not the same, it is the other player's turn. The problem that if player 1 stops in 20 seconds. player 2 also starts in 20 seconds. and it should start from 30 seconds each time. Who can help me with this? Thanks in advance

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".cards .card");
const currentPlayer = document.querySelector(".current-player");
const player1ScoreElement = document.querySelector(".player1-score");
const player2ScoreElement = document.querySelector(".player2-score");
const player1Timer = document.querySelector('.player1-timer');
const player2Timer = document.querySelector('.player2-timer');

let timer  ;
let timeLeft1 = 30;
let timeLeft2 = 30;

function startTimer() {
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (timeLeft1 <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      switchPlayers();
    } else {
      if (currentPlayer.textContent === "1") {
        player1Timer.textContent = timeLeft1;
         timeLeft1--;
      } else {
        player2Timer.textContent = timeLeft2;
        timeLeft2--;
      }
     
     
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function switchPlayers() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  if (currentPlayer.textContent === "1") {
    currentPlayer.textContent = "2";
    timeLeft2 = 30;
    player1Timer.classList.remove('active');
    player2Timer.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    currentPlayer.textContent = "1";
    timeLeft1 = 30;
    player2Timer.classList.remove('active');
    player1Timer.classList.add('active');
  }
  clearInterval(timer); // Stop the timer before starting it again
  timeLeft1 = 30; // reset the timer to 30 seconds
  timeLeft2 = 30;
  startTimer();
}

startTimer();
player1Timer.classList.add('active');
```

I want every player to start from 30 seconds. when player 2 gets his turn, he starts from 30 seconds. now start it at the same time of player 1 was finished

Comment: Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, and/or identify the specific operation observed during debugging which isn't doing what you expect?

Comment: Note that `setInterval` is not reliable in term of timing. It guarantees minimum of 1sec for your case, but it could be (much) longer if Javascript is busy doing other things (monothread language)

Comment: @Kaddath You can't say with certainty what the minimum amount of time will be. In actuality, it will be more like ~20 milliseconds, but depends on the browser internals.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I said 1 second for the OP's case, because an interval of 1000ms is used in the code (to decrement the timer), I was not talking about the minimal value of an interval

Comment: For your problem it seems we don't have enough information, as nothing looks wrong in the provided code, but my best bet is that you are displaying `timeLeft1` even when it's player 2 turn.

Comment: I tried your code as it is and it was working fine. What is the issue you are facing?